# Unable to use OpenCV in Visual Studio 2012 project

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am using MS Visual Studio 2012 and OpenCV 3.1. I want to compile this code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(){

    //Generate matrix to store image
    Mat image;

    //initialize capture
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);

    //Create window to show image
    namedWindow("window", 1);

    while (1){
        //copy webcam stream to image
        cap >> image;

        //print image to screen
        imshow("window", image);

        //delay 33ms
        waitKey(33);

    }

}
```

However, I am getting these errors:

```
Error   1   error C2065: 'videoCapture' : undeclared identifier C:\Users\patha\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\video\video\video.cpp  8   1   video
Error   2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cap' C:\Users\patha\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\video\video\video.cpp  8   1   video
Error   3   error C2065: 'cap' : undeclared identifier  C:\Users\patha\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\video\video\video.cpp  8   1   video
Error   4   error C2065: 'cap' : undeclared identifier  C:\Users\patha\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\video\video\video.cpp  9   1   video
Error   5   error C2228: left of '.open' must have class/struct/union   C:\Users\patha\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\video\video\video.cpp  9   1   video
Error   6   error C2065: 'cap' : undeclared identifier  C:\Users\patha\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\video\video\video.cpp  14  1   video
Error   7   error C3861: 'waitkey': identifier not found    C:\Users\patha\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\video\video\video.cpp  18  1   video
    8   IntelliSense: identifier "videoCapture" is undefined    c:\Users\patha\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\video\video\video.cpp  8   6   video
    9   IntelliSense: identifier "waitkey" is undefined c:\Users\patha\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\video\video\video.cpp  18  6   video
```

Answer (score 0):

To use OpenCV in VS, you will need to add its include path, i.e. `-path-to-OpenCV-3.1.0\build\include`, to your project's **Include Directories**.

Read [this post](http://www.hacktohell.org/2014/12/setting-up-opencv-300-with-visual.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The code is perfect and it works on my machine. The problem could be the compile doesn't recognize the OpenCV library. So, you need to set it correctly, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHX3MLzwF6Q) video will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like OpenCV 3.1.0 doesn't have vc11 library.
It only has vc12 & vc14.
Leaving you with a choice to install Visual Studio 2013 or later